# "Contact us" data in magento admin

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, contact-us

I am tired to find customer feedback in contact us form.Let me know where i can see contact us data in magento admin .

Comment: Hi Aman, this is not possible with Magento out of the box. There might be 3th party modules out there that do this but your question is a bit too broad to answer

Answer (score 7):

The the data from the "contact us" form is **not** stored in the magento admin. It is sent to the e-mail address configured under System > Configuration > Contacts.

Comment: This is just for email edit. I wants to be get and show all data in magento admin. like name email or comments in  admin .

Comment: If you want to display this in backend, you will have to build a custom module.. If you are new to magento, you can have a good start from here : http://www.pierrefay.com/magento-plugins-structure-22

Comment: Seems your question does not match your need then. You wanted to know where you can see it in the admin, the answer is: "nowhere".
If you want to have this data in the backend, you will need to implement this functionality (have a look at Mage_Contacts_IndexController and what happens out of the box). Or you find a module for this.

Comment: nice guidelines dude...!!!